# Using a list of tuples as indices for the product of columns in a 2D Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D numpy array `A` and a list of tuples `tup` that look like:

```
A = np.array(range(1,11)).reshape(-3,2)
A
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])

tup = [(0,),
 (1,),
 (0, 1),
 (0, 0),
 (1, 1),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1)]
```

I'm looking to create a new `np.array` as `result` whose columns are products of the columns of A: the indices of the columns to be used in the products are given by the values in the tuples. For example, the above should yield:

```
[[1,3,5,7,9],
[2,4,6,8,10],
[2,12,30,56,90],
[1,9,25,49,81],
[4,16,36,64,100],
[4,48,180,448,900],
...]]
```

Where the rows above correspond to:

```
[A[0],
A[1],
A[0]*A[1],
A[0]*A[0],
A[1]*A[1],
A[0]*A[1]*A[1],
A[1]*A[1]*A[1],
...]
```

The tuples can be of any length >= 1. So far I've tried iterating through each index of `tup` and looping through the number of entries of each tuple, but I'm having difficulty writing out the product given the number of terms per product varies for different iterations. Any help or direction is much appreciated! Slight preference towards base Python and/or Numpy solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [135]: A = np.array(range(1,11)).reshape(-3,2)
In [136]: tup = [(0,),
     ...:  (1,),
     ...:  (0, 1),
     ...:  (0, 0),
     ...:  (1, 1),
     ...:  (0, 1, 1),
     ...:  (1, 1, 1),
     ...:  (0, 0, 0),
     ...:  (0, 0, 1)]
```

Let's try some indexing

```
In [137]: A[0,tup[0]]
Out[137]: array([1])
In [138]: A[0,tup[1]]
Out[138]: array([2])
In [141]: A[0,tup[2]]
Out[141]: array([1, 2])
```

or for all rows of `A`:

```
In [142]: A[:,tup[2]]
Out[142]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

and the desired product:

```
In [143]: np.prod(A[:,tup[2]],axis=1)
Out[143]: array([ 2, 12, 30, 56, 90])
```

Now do this for a elements of `tup`.

```
[np.prod(A[:,k],axis=1) for k in tup]
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much! I knew there had to be a simple/elegant way of doing it and you nailed it :).